# How to localize list_display fields in Django admin?

Tags: django, localization, admin

I have float fields in the list_display of an ModelAdmin class, and I'd like them to be displayed localized (like 1.000,00). I already have USE_L10N and USE_I18N to True, but that's not enough.

The current solution I have is the following:

```
from django.utils import formats

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('localized_myfield')

   def localized_myfield(self, instance):
       return formats.localize(instance.myfield)
```

That works, but defining one method for each float field I have looks like a lot of unnecessary code. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after some research. To achieve what I want, three things are necessary:

- USE_L10N=True in settings.py
- USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR in settings.py
- myfield = forms.DecimalField(localize=True) in forms.py (I finally realized that DecimalField was better choice than Floatfield in my case)

Comment: localize=True works on edit form but how can add the localize on the list_display?